# Unable to start VS2012 Profiler

Tags: profiling, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to start a performance profiling session in Visual Studio 2012 RTM on Windows 8 PRO 64-bit for a console program (ANALYZE / Start Performance Analysis).

I get a popup message informing me

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.CounterInfo.dll' or one of its dependencies. The Specified module could not be found.

Apparently this can happen under VS2010 after KB2645410 is installed. I carefully followed the procedure given for this issue with the same error message:

[Visual Studio 2010 SP1, KB2645410 and Add-Ins](http://www.alex-maz.info/vs2010_profiler_error)

However, that does not resolve the issue.

I have tried running VS2012 as Administrator as well.

How can I get the profiler working?

**UPDATE**

I can actually attach to a running instance of the project from the command line using the steps here:

[Walkthrough: Command-Line Profiling Using Sampling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985628.aspx)

However, Visual Studio does not open the resulting .vspx file (it just does nothing after I open it with File / Open File).

**UPDATE 2**

Fuslogvw reports two binding errors when I attempt to start the profiler:

[VS 2012 Profiler Binding Errors - Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/16c2FnSa)

Comment: I seriously doubt the security patch could affect it, it fixes VS2010 specific files.  The assembly is mixed-mode with lots of native DLL dependencies.  Try using SysInternals' ProcMon to find the missing one.

Comment: @HansPassant: The claim is that the patch prevented Visual Studio from passing along it's credentials to profiler, and that by default the missing DLL is not accessible using the credentials that the profiler ends up running under.  At least a few people seem to have been able to resolve the issue by changing file permissions.  I'll try your suggestion of using ProcMon.

Comment: @HansPassant: The only thing that ProcMon indicates as a failure when attempting to start the profiler is NAME NOT FOUND for "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{FA445657-9379-11D6-B41A-00065B83EE53}" and "HKCR\CLSID\{FA445657-9379-11D6-B41A-00065B83EE53}".  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't have that coclass either.  It has something to do with text services.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was unable to reproduce the issue in a new, simple project on the same computer.  It continues to be an issue in the large, complex project where I really need the profiler to work.  FWIW, I opened a bug report with Microsoft https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768963/unable-to-start-vs2012-profiler  Given my inability to nail down exactly when this happens, I'm not very optimistic :-(

Comment: Better to use Support and send them the entire project.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a bunch of proprietary algorithms in the project.  And, for the price of a support ticket, I'm close enough to the cost of a Redgate profiler license without the hassle of waiting to see if/when MSFT can resolve the problem :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the following to the system path resolved the issue for me permanently.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
```

Some other answers may be appropriate to other situations.

Note that you probably will need to run Visual Studio as Administrator for profiling to work correctly.

Comment: This worked for me. Was running Windows 7, VS 2012. Added this to the system path and ran my VS as administrator and got it working.

Answer (score 5):

I also struggled with that issue.

I found a working solution for me:

I opende the XXX.sln file using notepad.

There i found several parts in the Project and Global Section looking something like this:

```
ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
    Performance1.psess = Performance1.psess
EndProjectSection
```

I removed all of them and that made my Analyzer work again.

Comment: The analyzer suddenly started working for me again, too.  I did happen to delete these from withing Visual Studio (under Solution Items).  That could well be why it works for me too.

Comment: Unfortunately things stopped working for me again, and there is no longer a .psess in my solution :-(  However leaving as accepted answer for now as it seems to help in at least some situations.

Comment: This worked for me, too. If it breaks again, I'll delete again... At least there's no need to reboot here :)

Answer (score 1):

I delete the .suo file and everythings works correctly now.

Comment: This did not help for me, but hopefully it helps some people.

Answer (score 1):

The same question exists here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6487155-980c-4bc8-82de-2fe588fdf37f/windows-update-kb2645410-and-performance-tools-error

The following are suggested workarounds:

- Remove windows update KB2645410
- Only run one instance of Visual Studio
- If you are the administrator on your development PC you can add the permission to Everyone to read and execute all the content in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools" and subfolders/files.
- "I backed everything up and did a complete repair of Visual Studio using the original disk from Microsoft. That allowed the computer to shut down normally. Then I tried the patch again. It hung again, but after a few reboots we got a message about deleting corrupt files and finally everything seems OK."

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved when I realized that my user access control was set too high. Once that was turned off, I rebooted and it all worked great.

Answer (score -1):

Once I uninstalled re-sharper my issue was resolved.