# Responsibility for Disposing Response Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, decorator

**Background**

I am considering integrating the `CompressFilter` from

[Removing extra whitespace from generated HTML in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855526/141172)

into my own code.  Before doing that, I want to measure time spent in the `CompressFilter`.  Since I [cannot use the Visual Studio Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13081515/141172), I decided to create a simple stream wrapper

```
private class BenchmarkStream : Stream
{
    Stream inner;

    public BenchmarkStream(Stream inner)
    {
        if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentException("inner");
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Compressed " + count + " bytes in " + 
           sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
    // Rest of implementation removed for brevity
}
```

to be used like

```
response.Filter = new BenchmarkStream(
                    new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress));
```

**Question**

Am I responsible for disposing my stream `inner` or is there a mechanism by will the ASP.Net runtime will do that?

The code for `CompressFilter` does not explicitly dispose the `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream` assigned to `response.Filter`, but I don't see how the runtime can dispose of `inner`.

Do I assume correctly that `GZipStream` and `DeflateStream` are responsible for disposing the stream it composes?